# How to use entity_metadata_wrapper for users particulary in hook_user_presave

Tags: 7, entities, users

For node I can use the entity_metadata_wrapper like below

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $ewrapper->title->set('new title');
}
```

However how can I use the entity_metadata_wrapper for users. I want to use entity_metadata_wrapper in hook_user_presave.

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  ???
}
```

this variant works for me:

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $edit_object = (object) $edit;
  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $edit_object);
  $field_telefon = $ewrapper->field_telefon->value();
  $ewrapper->field_telefon->set($field_telefon.'123');
  $edit = (array)$edit_object;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting $edit as an object:

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', (object) $edit);
}
```

Comment: How to update user fields for an exisiting user using entity_metadata_wrapper?